# Conceptual 'Class Model' mapping an 'Observer Pattern' in UML

Tags: design-patterns, uml, associations, observer-pattern, class-diagram

I am drawing a conceptual UML Class Diagram based on an Observer Pattern between a UI layer and a mapped domain, where the publisher pushes notifications in the form of SQL queries to the different classes creating records in a SQL database. The model so far looks as following (purely conceptual, note the not yet implemented methods from the ISubscriber interface):
[image]

I have some questions regarding the different types of associations between the classes.

- What type of association exists between ISubscriber and IPublisher?
- What type of association exists between the domain layer classes and the `DataAccess class` supposed to contain the SqlConnection? Assuming the interface methods are overwritten and pushes SQl queries to `DataAccess class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPublisher needs to know its subscribers to be able to push the notifications.  This means that there is an **association** between the `IPublisher` and `*` `ISubscriber`.

Since the `IPublisher` needs to find efficiently its subscribers, you may even indicate that the association is navigable from publisher to subscriber.

It is not clear if your design should allow an `ISubscriber` to subscribe to only one `IPublisher` or if it can subscribe to more than one. If you already know, you may wish to specify the opposite multiplicity accordingly.  Keep in mind that implementations of the observer pattern with multi-subscription, rarely need a reverse navigability: usually, the notification is then designed in a way to indicate the relevant publisher (e.g.: ISubscriber would have a `notify(IPublisher from)` operation or reception.

Regarding the associations of domain classes with data access classes, your question is too broad, as it depends on your chosen architecture.  For example, you may use:

- the [active record pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) where every domain object takes care of its DB operations (i.e. DB class and Domain class are the same),
- the [repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), where a repository for relevant aggregates deal with the DB (i.e., Domain object does know nothing about DB) and the rest of the application inserts or extracts domain objects into/from the repository, as if it were a container/collection.
- several variants of gateway pattern, such as the [table data pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html),  where a gateway is in charge of the DB,  but the object deals with the gateway (i.e. there is a dependency from domain class to the DB gateway, or even an association if dependency injection is used).
- Many others (I can only recommend having a look at the [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), a book which is a really good investment)

Comment: This is a great answer - I believe the active record pattern fits my model as the classes contain the raw informaton for direct injection into the DB, which is done with the `DataAccess` class. I have associated ISubscriber with IPublisher through a zero to one in regards to IPublisher ← ISubscriber (showing a loose coupling and the ability to arbitrarily swap UI) and a zero to many in regards to IPublisher → ISubscriber (the UI can send information to zero or many classes to the DB).

The only thing I am missing is the type of connection to `DataAccess`
https://imgur.com/a/GBysLto

Comment: @Aleksandar if the domain objects create some DataAccess objects and operate it,  it would be a simple dependency. But from the exposed API, I understand that the domain objects use a DataAccess object they need to know, and call it with themselves as argument (i.e. in a language which offers reflexivity).  If so,  you would probably need a navigable association if each object keep track of a DataAccess object (potentially different instances could even use different data bases).  On the other side,  if each of the domain object would find back the relevant DataAccess instance (global? .../...

Comment: ../.. service discovery?, ...) then again, a simple dependency would be sufficient.